Can i use EOS Notechain boilerplate to achieve Multi org setup?
I am building a supply chain DApp using Notechain, which works well in a local single-node environment. Now, I want to expand it to a multi-node setup to make it more distributed.

What are the key considerations and steps for scaling this application to multiple nodes?
Additionally, when moving from a local environment to a production
environment, what aspects should I be aware of to ensure smooth
deployment, security, and scalability?

With reference to the below question with code:
Multi-Org Testnet fails in synchronizing. (Using EOS notechain boilerplate)
